# Pattern using looping

Tags: java

I have to make a loop that will read the user's input (let's say his input is 5) so the output should be as the following:-

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

---

```
int x;
//input size of triangle from 1-20
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter size of triangle from 1 to 20: ");
x = scanner.nextInt ();

for( int i = 0; i <= x; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < i; j++){
        System.out.print( " *");
    }
        System.out.println(" ");
```

I just don't know how to finish it by decreasing the pattern so I can form a full triangle.

Comment: This looks like homework... It's better for you to struggle through it, as it's a fairly trivial problem to solve.

Comment: I don't understand why you're printing whitespaces. That is not necessary for that kind of "diamond". And you don't need nested loops here. Use two separate loops instead.

Comment: @wjohnsto Actually I didn't really want people to solve the question for me i just wanted help and tips to help me with the question, and i agree that it's better to struggle throughout it. thanks for the advise

Comment: @Violetx you accept a answer and upvote if they helped u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code prints the triangle, assuming the user enters 10

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (int j = 0;j < i;j++ )
    System.out.print('x');
    System.out.println();
}
for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--){
    for (int j = 0; j < i;j++)
    System.out.print('x');
    System.out.println();
}
```

In your code, you exclude the second for loop in which i is decremented.

Comment: `good luck.` with what? You already solved the whole assignment. Not much to do for OP here.

Comment: Thanks for your help and comment it really helped me and i changed some part of your answer to match the question am solving, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

example using ternary operator .increase j if x grater than i decrease otherwise

```
int x = 5, j=0;

for (int i = 0; i <= x*2; i++) {
    j= (x>i)? ++j:--j;   // u can use if else also
    for (int y = 0; y < j; y++) {
        System.out.print(" *");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

output>>

```
 *
 * *
 * * *
 * * * *
 * * * * *
 * * * * * *
 * * * * *
 * * * *
 * * *
 * *
 *
```

Comment: This is a great help thanks for answering my question i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {
    public static void printLine(int n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of triangle");
        int x = scanner.nextInt ();

        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            printLine(i);
        }

        for(int i = x; i > 0; i--) {
            printLine(i);
        }
    }   
}
```

The output :

```
Enter size of triangle
5

*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: I haven't used the print line method before but i guess i will learn how to use it, thanks for your answer!

Comment: the printLine method is just the function a written just before :)